# System.Reflection GetNestetTypes All fields declared Name or value

Tags: c#, reflection, nested-class, fieldinfo

how do i get a list of all fields within all nested classes

```
class AirCraft
{
    class fighterJets
    {
        public string forSeas = "fj_f18";
        public string ForLand = "fj_f15";
    }
    class helicopters 
    {
        public string openFields = "Apachi";
        public string CloseCombat = "Cobra";

    }
}
```

the code i am trying to use is from one of the posts here
i can break this into two or three separeted lines of code and it will work 
the question is about the expression , and using shortest/modern code.

```
IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetAllFields(Type type) {
    return type.GetNestedTypes().SelectMany(GetAllFields)
               .Concat(type.GetFields());
}
```

this will return fieldInfo not the names or values,
and i need it more as a list of string or better a dictionary for both fields-values and names
but a list will do for now.

```
List<string> (or dictionary) ChosenContainersNamesOrValuesOfAllNested(Type T)
{
   return a shortest syntax for that task, using lambda rather foreach
}
```

thanks.

Comment: How could you get the values of the fields without an instance of each of the classes?  Your fields aren't static.

Comment: @KirkWoll in my program it is. though it is good to see both examples with and without an instance

Comment: if in your "program it is", then it is elsewhere than in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use Linq's [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) extension method to get just the names:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetAllFieldNames(Type type)
{
    // uses your existing method
    return GetAllFields(type).Select(f => f.Name);
}
```

Or the [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) extension method to construct a dictionary:

```
IDictionary<string, object> GetAllFieldNamesAndValues(object instance) 
{
    return instance.GetType()
        .GetFields()
        .ToDictionary(f => f.Name, f => f.GetValue(instance));
}
```

Note you will need an instance of the type to get the values. Also, this will only work for a single type, since you will need an instance of each type to get the values.

However, if you defined your fields as static you could do this:

```
class AirCraft
{
    public class fighterJets
    {
        public static string forSeas = "fj_f18";
        public static string ForLand = "fj_f15";
    }
    public class helicopters 
    {
        public static string openFields = "Apachi";
        public static string CloseCombat = "Cobra";

    }
}

IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetAllStaticFields(Type type) 
{
    return type.GetNestedTypes().SelectMany(GetAllFields)
               .Concat(type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static));
}


IDictionary<string, object> GetAllStaticFieldNamesAndValues(Type type) 
{
    return GetAllStaticFields(type)
        .ToDictionary(f => f.Name, f => f.GetValue(null));
}
```

This works because static fields are not bound to any instance of the class.